# ng-repeat is not fetching value from an Array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having trouble in getting values from an array using `ng-repeat` inside a select drop down. Being a newbie in AngularJS, i'm sure i have made a mistake somewhere in the following codes:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <option ng-repeat="item in sampleArray" value="{{item['Product Description']}}">{{item['Product Description']}}</option>
</select>
```

Below is my array

```
 var sampleArray = [{'Vanilla Product Code':'a1','Product Description':'b1'},{'Vanilla Product Code':'a2','Product Description':'b2'}];
```

Any suggestions will be most welcomed.

Comment: Downvoters, please consider adding a comment before down voting !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine.

I think you are not referencing the `sampleArray` with `$scope`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14978/) is the JsFiddle

Comment: Thanks for your answer..you were correct about the referencing with $scope !!

Answer (score 2):

You should use ng-options.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="it['Vanilla Product Code'] as it['Product Description'] for it in sampleArray">
</select>
```

See demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/b4aSjJ?p=info

Comment: Thanks for your answer...:) but the drop down in the demo is not displaying the values either.

Comment: Does for me: http://monosnap.com/image/VJNxUU08dE1gpiBc5dAjvOSC0gZugG.png. I assumed you want descriptions for the labels. If not, tweak the ng-options definition, should be crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="names=[{'Vanilla Product Code':'a1','Product Description':'b1'},{'Vanilla Product Code':'a2','Product Description':'b2'}]">
      <select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="item in names" value="{{item['Product Description']}}">{{item['Product Description']}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :).. but i was looking for array to be passed from the controller side.